# Retrying query on deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Lately, in our estate, we noticed an increase of deadlocks on certain set of stored procedures, these are quite straightforward:

- Insert into a table
- Update records in a table based on primary key

This table has *too many* triggers and these ocasionally clash with another stored procedure, that runs on an hourly basis and result in a deadlock.

I was googling around and stumbled upon this article: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/

It suggests following pattern to handle deadlocking procedures:

```
DECLARE @retries INT ;
SET @retries = 4 ;

WHILE ( @retries > 0 ) 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION ;

         -- place sql code here
            SET @retries = 0 ;

            COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH 
        -- Error is a deadlock
            IF ( ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205 ) 
                SET @retries = @retries - 1 ;

        -- Error is not a deadlock
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) ;
                    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT ;
                    DECLARE @ErrorState INT ;

                    SELECT  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,
                            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() ,
                            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE() ;

                    -- Re-Raise the Error that caused the problem
                    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                       @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                       @ErrorState -- State.
                       ) ;
                    SET @retries = 0 ;
                END

            IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        END CATCH ;
    END ;
GO
```

It pretty much gives code a second, third and fourth chance to succeed and only then throws an error.

My question is whether this is a healthy pattern to handle deadlocks in edgy situations and is an actual solution rather than workaround to a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this answer is only an opinion :)

That solution looks like it would work to me.  However, I do not believe it is an actual solution, but a workaround.  It would be preferable instead try and figure out what is causing your deadlocks to begin with and solve that.

If you cannot solve the cause of the deadlocks, then a workaround such as this wouldn't be terrible, but truly is just working-around the actual problem.

Comment: That's what I actually thought myself. Right now I want to eliminate them and read more literature. Everything is too tangled to fix things quick.